# Storing userID and other data and using it to query database

Tags: html, security, cordova, local-storage

I am developing an app with PhoneGap and have been storing the user id and user level in local storage, for example:

```
window.localStorage["userid"] = "20";
```

This populates once the user has logged in to the app. This is then used in ajax requests to pull in their information and things related to their account (some of it quite private). The app is also been used in web browser as I am using the exact same code for the web. Is there a way this can be manipulated? For example user changes the value of it in order to get info back that isnt theirs?

If, for example another app in their browser stores the same key "userid" it will overwrite and then they will get someone elses data back in my app.

How can this be prevented?

Comment: I am not an expert in security. As you have said a user can forge someone else id and get access to unauthorized data. Why don't you use session tokens that are generated at the backend(Server) and use it to authenticate the transactions. The session token can be stored in the localstorage. Session tokens are randomly generated and would be difficult for the user to guess the tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before go further attack vectors, storing these kind of sensitive data on client side is not good idea. Use token instead of that because every single data that stored in client side can be spoofed by attackers.

Your considers are right. Possible attack vector could be related to Insecure Direct Object Reference. Let me show one example.

You are storing userID client side which means you can not trust that data anymore.

```
window.localStorage["userid"] = "20";
```

Hackers can change that value to anything they want. Probably they will changed it to less value than 20. Because most common use cases shows that 20 is coming from column that configured as auto increment. Which means there should be valid user who have userid is 19, or 18 or less.

Let me assume that your application has a module for getting products by userid. Therefore backend query should be similar like following one.

```
SELECT * FROM products FROM owner_id = 20
```

When hackers changed that values to something else. They will managed to get data that belongs to someone else. Also they could have chance to remove/update data that belongs to someone else agains.

Possible malicious attack vectors are really depends on your application and features. As I said before you need to figure this out and do not expose sensitive data like userID.

Using token instead of userID is going solved that possible break attemps. Only things you need to do is create one more columns and named as "token" and use it instead of userid. ( Don't forget to generate long and unpredictable token values )

```
SELECT * FROM products FROM owner_id = iZB87RVLeWhNYNv7RV213LeWxuwiX7RVLeW12
```